# How to map values of a certain column in ggplot of r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

here is my code :

```
ggplot(subset(df,!is.na(LoanStatus)),aes(x=LoanStatus)) + 
  geom_bar()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

here is the resulted plot:
[image]

My question is:
How can i merge the boxes named "past due" into just one box.
How can i map the values in the column "LoanStatus"?

Thanks!

Comment: df$LoanStatusPlotting <- gsub("Past Due.*", "Past Due", df$LoanStatus) Build a new column with the bins you want for plotting

Comment: Thanks, Nathan, That works

Answer (score 0):

Use `mutate` function from `dplyr` package to create a new variable and substitute factors `PastDue...` with `PastDue`, where `grepl` will return `TRUE` when there is substring of `PastDue` in the `LoanStatus` column:

```
library(dplyr);
ggplot(mutate(subset(df,!is.na(LoanStatus)), 
              LoanStatus = ifelse(grepl("PastDue", LoanStatus), "PastDue", LoanStatus)),
       aes(x=LoanStatus)) + 
       geom_bar()+
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```